# Need advice on finding forward spot rates

Tags: futures, interest-rates

So this is a "work homework" question. As part of my job they are sending us through sort of a training course. I'm looking for advice, or a link to a site that explains how to do this with maybe some formulas or something. I am NOT looking for answers. I want to figure this stuff out myself, I just need a little guidance.

Here is the question:

> **Given Information**
>
> 3-month Libor 1.85%
>
> 6-month Libor
> 1.94625%
>
> 12-month Libor 2.06%
>
> Find the following:
>
> 3-month Libor 3 months forward
>
> 6-month
> Libor 6 months forward
>
> 3-month Libor 6
> months forward
>
> 3-month Libor 9 months
> forward
>
> **ASSUMPTION**
>
> **Assume 30/360 day count and even quarterly periods**

Thanks guys.

Comment: if these were actual data, at the moment you raised the question, does it happen you to have the observed values for the rates you were asking? (What was the 3ML after 3M, what was the 6ML after 6 M, etc) And could you say the currency these Libors are for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for good explanation with example than you may want to consider reading Jim Harper aka Bionic Turtle and his article  on [forward rates and spot rates](http://www.bionicturtle.com/how-to/article/forward_rates_and_spot_rates/). You can find excel spreadsheet for given example there as well.

Comment: I got 2.033% for the first one and 2.152% for the second, but how do I get the 9 month libor rate? don't i need that to solve the last 2?

Comment: You know the 9-month Libor is between 1.94625% and 2.06%, so you can 
get some estimates for the last two? You also know the relation 
between the last 2 (they must "add" to 2.152%). This might get you 
some fairly tight estimates.

Comment: @AndreyTaptunov your embedded link to Bionic Turtle is no longer available. I am not sure if this is as same as his video tutoril on Youtube. I still find it hard to apply the concept to a question I have and most probably I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

Another good resource is "Investment Science" by David Luenberger (chapter 4).  I'm actually doing "school homework" on the subject right now.  I'm guessing you'll find this book good for future assignments as well.